# webpack css-loader + file-loader different results on win/mac

Tags: webpack, css-loader, webpack-file-loader

I have this case, working fine on Mac... but when I cloned the repo on a Windows computer the build generates different results (paths) and it's not working.

All routes are relative to the build path:

**fonts/abc.ttf**

```
ttf file existing here
```

**styles/styles.less**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'abc';
  src: url(../fonts/abc.ttf);
}
```

**examples/example.ts**

```
import '../styles/styles.less';
```

**webpack.config**

```
{
  test: /\.(css|scss|sass|less)$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
          importLoaders: 1,
          namedExport: true,
          camelCase: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          localIdentName: '[local]',
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: { plugins: () => [autoprefixer('ie >= 9')] },
      },
    ],
  }),
},
{
  test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      useRelativePath: true,
      outputPath: 'fonts',
    },
  }],
},
```

In the mac environment, the output is correct:

- the font is placed in `fonts/abc.ttf`
- the css file loads it properly with `url(../fonts/abc.ttf)`

In windows however:

- the font is placed in `fonts/fonts/abc.ttf`
- the css file tries to load it with `url(fonts/fonts/abc.ttf)` (giving that the css file is placed in `/examples/example.css` the resulting url would be `/examples/fonts/fonts/abc.ttf` so it's a 404

So basically 2 questions:

- why the url is duplicated (as `fonts/fonts`)?
- why the css is not able to detect properly the relative url and add the `..` to its path?

And well, above all, why the results are not the same in win/mac?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but I think this is related to the webpack setting `node : { __dirname : "mock" }`  which is the default and makes `__dirname` result in `/`. I think there are instances this will not be interpreted the same on mac an windows (most likely in how some loader or plugin handles it). I would try with `{ node: { __dirname: false }}` instead.  Also having ran into quirks with outputPath before, I would give up on changing the `outputPath` when possible. You can use `name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',` and there'll be less side effects. (Sorry, no real answer here!)

Comment: @ippi got the error. Was a bug? of file-loader. In mac 1.1.6 version was installed, in Win 1.1.11... even if the yarn.lock resolved both to the same file (why?) but anyways, fixing the version fixed the problem. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to different versions being installed (1.1.6 vs 1.1.11)
It might be that the latests introduce a bug, but installing the same version fixed the problem.

PS: Different versions was caused due to cleaning yarn.lock for different reasons.